# Maven: meaning of repository ID

Tags: maven

In my POM file, I'm specifying two repositories:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>myid</id>
        <url>http://url1</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>myid</id>
        <url>http://url2</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

So, from the Maven documentation, I got the impression that the `id` element should cross-reference with a `settings.xml` `server` entry, to specify authentication information. Both `http://url1` and `http://url2`, in my case, require the very same authentication data; that is why I'm using the same `id` for both.

Still, Maven complains, saying that the `id` element must be unique.

What gives? What exactly is that purpose of the `id` element? I know (for sure) that Maven uses it to get authentication data - which is why things work when I only specify one repository. Why do I have to duplicate my authentication data? what am I missing?

Comment: [As here is said](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Servers) it looks like Maven links every single repository with a server entry. It seems you'll have to create two server entries, but you don't have to duplicate your credentials, just set them like properties and use them into each of your entry.

Comment: @XtremeBiker, properties defined inside `settings.xml` are only within the context of a profile. For some reason, those properties are not expanded for the `server` elements.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ID has to be unique. Use 2 login configurations in your settings.xml.

Comment: Hmmm. I consider this to be a design flaw. Someone forgot to normalize something. But thank you.

Comment: Looks more that they should be unique but does not have to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21836539/sonatype-nexus-how-to-set-a-single-server-credentials-for-multiple-repositories?rq=1

Comment: Also, what's the difference between `id` and `name` ?

Comment: @Nom1fan looks like `name` is optional while `id` mandatory

Comment: @Robert why do you claim they *should* be unique?

Comment: on my Maven 3.6.1 they seem to work when duplicated.