# Sonatype Nexus: How to set a single server credentials for multiple repositories in maven's settings.xml?

Tags: maven, nexus, sonatype

We have multiple repositories in Nexus (i.e., releases, snapshot and site). All 3 repos are under public group and users uses the same credentials to access all these repositories. Providing the same username and password in settings.xml for each repository makes it redundant and hard to maintain them.

Could you please suggest an elegant way to describe one server credential for all the 3 repositories?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

We are using maven 2.2.1 and Nexus OSS 2.7.1

**Here is my settings.xml**

```
<settings>    
<servers>   
<server>   
    <id>snapshot</id>   
    <username>deployment</username>   
    <password>deployment123</password>      
</server>  
<server>   
       <id>release</id>   
       <username>deployment</username>  
       <password>deployment123</password>      
</server>  
<server>  
      <id>site</id>  
      <username>deployment</username>  
      <password>deployment123</password>   
</server>  
 </servers>  
  <mirrors>  
    <mirror>  
      <!--This sends everything else to /public -->  
      <id>nexus</id>  
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>  
      <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>  
    </mirror>  
  </mirrors>  
  <profiles>  
    <profile>  
      <id>nexus</id>  
      <!--Enable snapshots for the built in central repo to direct -->  
      <!--all requests to nexus via the mirror -->  
      <repositories>  
        <repository>  
          <id>central</id>  
          <url>http://central</url>  
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>  
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>  
        </repository>  
      </repositories>  
      <pluginRepositories>  
        <pluginRepository>  
          <id>central</id>  
          <url>http://central</url>  
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>  
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>  
        </pluginRepository>  
       </pluginRepositories>  
 </profile>  
  </profiles>  
  <activeProfiles>  
    <!--make the profile active all the time -->  
    <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>  
  </activeProfiles>  
</settings>
```

Comment: if their was a solution, i'd be happy to hear it as well - but then again, it's not that bad having three different usernames in there

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just use one entry in setttings.xml like that

```
<server>   
    <id>nexus</id>   
    <username>deployment</username>   
    <password>deployment123</password>      
</server>
```

and then in distributionManagement in your pom.xml's you use something like that

```
<distributionManagement>
<repository>
  <id>nexus</id>
  <name>Nexus Releases</name>
  <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
</repository>
<snapshotRepository>
  <id>nexus</id>
  <name>Nexus Snapshot</name>
  <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
</snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

For fully working setup with this look at the [Nexus Book Examples project](https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-book-examples/) that are used in the trial guide. You can add a site with the same id as well, of course. Keep in mind that there is no problem if the id;s are the same as they just detail the identifier of the server element in settings to look for and are NOT an id element for the repository. Imho it should be called serverId or something to be clearer, but thats a different story.

Comment: I have observed that if there are multiple repositories with the same "id" as in this answer then maven build was only trying to reach only the last repo in sequence and ignoring the rest ones..

Answer (score 4):

Not a solution but a workaround:

settings.xml will [handle system properties and environment variables](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html).  So if you're not fussed about putting your server authentication details in a script or in your environment, you can stick with three server credentials but eliminate the need to update all three of them in favour of updating your script or environments (I've put examples for both options in this snippet):

```
<servers>
  <server>
    <id>releases</id>
    <username>${env.NEXUS_USERNAME}</username> <!-- Env var -->
    <password>${nexus.password}</password> <!-- System (-D) var -->
  </server>
  <server>
    <id>snapshots</id>
    <username>${env.NEXUS_USERNAME}</username> <!-- Env var -->
    <password>${nexus.password}</password> <!-- System (-D) var -->
  </server>
  <server>
    <id>site</id>
    <username>${env.NEXUS_USERNAME}</username> <!-- Env var -->
    <password>${nexus.password}</password> <!-- System (-D) var -->
  </server>
</servers>
```

Unfortunately there's no `<properties>` element supported in settings.xml!

Aside: maven already handles the snapshots and releases repositories within nexus, and that is the better way to do things.  Your posted settings.xml even enables them already.  Why do you need separate repository entries for snapshots and releases?

Comment: Paul, thank you for the quick turn around. Unfortunately we cannot have the credentials in environment variable :( and as you said `<properties>` element doesn't work. Firstly,

Comment: I didn't think it would be much of a goer, it's not the most secure of options!  You could put the values in a script.  -Dnexus.username=repoUser -Dnexus.password=repoPwd will work.  But again, not the most secure, since the values would be visible in your process list.

Comment: Paul, thank you for the quick turn around. Unfortunately we cannot have the credentials in environment variable :( and as you said `<properties>` element didn't work. Firstly, I am not sure where you see separate repository entries for snapshots and releases. I have only one repository entry called 'central' and mirror of to my public group. And without the server entries (id, username and password) for snapshots, site and releases. I would get an 401 - access denied error when I do a build.

Comment: We are using a common machine to do our build and we would be encrypting our passwords. So the environmental variable is not ideal for us.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you mistaken things here. The given credentials and id's are for the distributionManagement and not for the access to the Nexus in this case. Apart from that you need three different username, password combinations cause you have three possible things **releases**, **snapshots** and **site**. So not a big deal.

Aprt from that i would suggest to upgrade Maven into Maven 3.X line cause Maven 2.2.1 is a little bit out of date.

Comment: Thank you for the quick turn around! Yes, I do understand those credentials are for distributionManagement. I'm just wondering if there is a best way to specify the username and password only once  and use it where I want.

Comment: And yeah, we are also planning to migrate to Maven 3.0 shortly.

Comment: No you can't define it only once. There are three areas where you need it and so you have to define it three times if you have the same. But i don't see it as a big problem having three entries in the settings.xml file.

Comment: See my answer... you can use it in multiple places just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the id of the mirror in the server id:

```
<servers>
    <server>
        <id>nexus</id>
        <username>USERNAME</username>
        <password>PASSWORD</password>
    </server>
</servers>
<mirrors>
    <mirror>
        <id>nexus</id>
        <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
        <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>  
    </mirror>  
</mirrors>
```