# How to get around "'repositories.repository.id' must be unique" during mvn install

Tags: maven

Maven (3.6.3)

I have a pom.xml with below remote repository info:

```
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>artifactory</id>
            <url>https://abc.io/artifactory/foo</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>artifactory</id>
            <url>https://abc.io/artifactory/bar</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

When I do `mvn clean install`, I get an error saying `'repository.id' must be unique..` so I am guessing this is a limitation with Maven. I checked answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15011250/maven-meaning-of-repository-id), but I am not sure how to set up two login credentials in `settings.xml` and even if I get it to work on my local, I don't think I can build & deploy on a remote Jenkins server, since I dont have admin access to override `settings.xml`.

Is there a different setup that works? Or am I misunderstanding this completely?

Updated settings.xml

```
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>foo</id>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>artifactory</id>
                    <url>https://abc.io/artifactory/foo</url>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>bar</id>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>artifactory</id>
                    <url>https://abc.io/artifactory/bar</url>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>foo</activeProfile>
        <activeProfile>bar</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
```

Comment: First as described in the answer of J Fabian Meier  already and simply use unique id's. This is not a limitation this the idea of id (identifier) which is uniqueness... and usually the url's for each id differ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is usually best to declare repositories in the `settings.xml`.

So you should probably talk to your Jenkins admins if they can amend the `settings.xml` or provide you with an additional one.

Comment: Thank you Fabian, can you take a look at what my editted answer for local `settings.xml` and see if it is correct?

Comment: You still have the same id twice.

Comment: Yes. That is my concern. the id has to be the same for both repositories in order to download them. I was looking more for something like `<id></id><urls><url>...`

Comment: Why not just use different ids?

Comment: Yes. You are correct. I didn't realize that I could just add another <server><server> with a different id.